# exponential value conversion to decimal value using php

Tags: php

I have have some variable to which i want to calculate

```
$a=10;
$b=.00005;
$c=.001;
```

Now  i calculate

```
$d=($a*($b*$c));
```

It should output

```
.000005
```

But its give me out put

```
0;
```

After manipulating line by line i found that, script calculating the value of $b * C

```
$b* $c =5E-6;
$d=$a* 5E-6;
```

SO after complete calculation the whole result become 0

I have used bcmath's bcmul() function, but nothing happen.

So anybody tell me how i can fix this issue.

Comment: `$d` comes out to be `5.0E-7` in PHP 5.3

Comment: Yes i am using php5.3 and it give me the same error but i dont how to convert this exponent value into decimal value. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
$a=10;
$b=.00005;
$c=.001;
$d=($a*($b*$c));

var_dump ($d ); 
// float(5.0E-7)

var_dump (number_format($d, 7)); 
// string(9) "0.0000005"
```

Works like expected.

Comment: My question is how to convert 5.0E-7 into decimal.

Comment: See answer posted by me @Vish.

Answer (score 0):

It is showing correct answer.You might be using number_format() with wrong parameters,I guess.
Try following code.

```
    $a=10;
    $b=.00005;
    $c=.001;
    $d=($a*($b*$c));
    echo number_format($d,10);
```